# Extra line is coming as output in c++

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
string n;
int number_of_test_cases;
cin>>number_of_test_cases;
for (int i = 0; i <= number_of_test_cases; i++) {
    getline(cin,n);
    for (int p = 0; p < n.size(); p++)
    {
        if (p%2==0){
            cout<<n[p];
        }
    }cout<<" ";
    for (int p = 0; p < n.size(); p++)
    {
        if (p%2!=0){
            cout<<n[p];
        }
    }cout<<endl;
}return 0;}
```

This code first takes number of test cases as input number_of_test_cases ,then it runs loop n times in which it first takes input string then it runs a loop to print even indexed characters then space then again runs a loop to print odd indexed characters then it prints a endline.

Now the problem is that after giving number_of_test_cases as input it is printing a unwanted line. So now i want to get rid of that extra line.

This question is from hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem

for input
2
Hacker
Rank
its giving output

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

instead of

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

Comment: please include desired and actual output in the question

Comment: you say `n` is the number of testcases but it is declared as a `string`?

Comment: your variable naming scheme is confusing (apparently for you and for others). Using meaningful names is the first step towards readable code. Eg `j` could be `number_of_test_cases`

Comment: How many times do you think this loop runs `for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++) {`? If `j` is zero then it runs once, if `j` is one then it runs twice, if `j` is two then it runs three times. I'm sure you can see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cin.ignore()` after scanning the integer before using getline function. Also the condition in your for loop should be `i < j`.